# Duplicate symbol errors with AdMob SDK in Xamarin.iOS against ARMv7 and ARMv7s

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, admob

I'm trying to integrate Google AdMob SDK into my [Xamarin.iOS](http://xamarin.com/ios) App. I installed the [Google AdMob component](http://components.xamarin.com/view/googleadmob/) from the [Xamarin Component Store](http://components.xamarin.com) and got it working on both simulator and device with debug builds.

But as soon as I add `ARMv7s` under supported architectures in iOS Build options for release builds the compilation fails with errors like this one:

```
duplicate symbol _tohex in:
    /Users/redent/Documents/workspace/MovieLend/MovieLend.Touch/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/mtouch-cache/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(rc4.o)
    /Users/redent/Documents/workspace/MovieLend/MovieLend.Touch/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/mtouch-cache/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
ld: 42 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7s
```

([Complete compilation log file](https://gist.github.com/redent/6965856))

I'm using other native libraries without problems, and I think that others are using the AdMob SDK without issues. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello in order to get this working you need to download the latest version of the [AdMob Component v6.5.1.2](https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleadmob/) this contains a fix for it. Additional to that you need to add `--registrar:static` to your additional mono touch arguments like this.

[image]

You can read more about type registrars [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/registrar/).

Hope this helps.

Alex